# Tweepy follow users who don't follow me

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I grabbed a list of followers from another account and need to follow them all. But the default loop goes through the whole list of users, including people I already follow so I need to exclude them. Basically, I check if show_friendship method returns False from json node and follow user if it happens. For some reason, code after second if statement (if friendship == "False":) never starts and I cannot follow anyone.

Here is the method I created:

```
def follow_account_followers(account_followers_ids):
    followers_count = 0

    for account_follower_id in account_followers_ids:
        if followers_count < 7:
            try:
                friendship = api.show_friendship(target_id=account_follower_id)[1].followed_by
                print friendship
                print account_follower_id
                followers_count += 1

                if friendship == "False": #check if we follow the user from array (not a bool value)
                    print followers_count
                    api.create_friendship(target_id=account_follower_id[follow])
                    print 'Following {}'.format(account_follower_id)
                else:
                    continue

            except tweepy.error.TweepError:
                continue
```

Comment: Can you show your debug(print) statements?

Comment: it just prints True/False and user id. print followers_count doesn't run because "if" control is never triggered for some reason.

Comment: True/False are you sure they are sting object. Can you try 'if not friendship: print followers_count'?

Comment: tried with "if no friendship", result is the same. I guess it is a string because it is derived from json output

Comment: if you are checking against json string try changing it to `false` instead of `False`